# Having each cell be editable when i am using php and html is it possible?

Tags: php, html, css, jeditable

I have downloaded judicable and tried incoperating within my code in order to establish the editable cells and return the value back to php. I have looked at a couple of examples they keep referring to the value and it is into working with my current code below.

Is there any way for my current code to have editable cells?

```
if(!$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")) {
     echo "Cannot connect to db server";
}
elseif(!mysql_select_db("Disney")) {
     echo "Cannot select database";
}
else {
     if(!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DisneyCharacters")) {
          echo "Cannot parse query";
     }
     elseif(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
          echo "No records found";
     }
     else {
//      Name, Movie, year, ShoeSize, FavoriteColor, FavoriteFood, PhoneNumber, CharacterType, FavoriteDrink, Address, FavortieTvShow, School, Age, HouseSqFoot, RelationShip, Rating, CarModel, CarYear, Boyfriend,
// NumberFriends, CriminalHistory, HappyEnding, FavoriteLocation, AppleDevice, WorkLocation, Weight, RepublicanDemocratic, DressColor, Shampoo, NumberKids) 

          echo "<table  width=\"400\" height=\"1\" id=\"sortedtable\" class=\"draggable sortable\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
          echo "<thead>\n<tr>";
          echo "<th>Name  </th>";
          echo "<th>Movie  </th>";
          echo "<th>Year  </th>";
          echo "<th>Shoe Size </th>";
          echo "<th>Favorite Color </th>";
          echo "<th>Favorite Food </th>";
          echo "<th>Phone Number </th>";
          echo "<th>Character Type </th>";
          echo "<th>Favorite Drink </th>";
          echo "<th>Address </th>";
          echo "<th>Favorite TvShow </th>";
          echo "<th>School </th>";
          echo "<th>Age </th>";
          echo "<th>HouseSqFoot </th>";
          echo "<th>Relationship </th>";
          echo "<th>Rating </th>";
          echo "<th>Car Model </th>";
          echo "<th>Car Year </th>";
          echo "<th>Boyfriend </th>";
          echo "<th>Number Friends </th>";
          echo "<th>Criminal History </th>";
          echo "<th>Happy Ending </th>";
          echo "<th>Favorite Location </th>";
          echo "<th>Apple Device </th>";
          echo "<th>Work Location </th>";
          echo "<th>Weight</th>";
          echo "<th>Republican Democratic </th>";
          echo "<th>Dress Color </th>";
          echo "<th>Shampoo </th>";
          echo "<th>Number Kids </th>";
echo "</tr>\n</thead>\n";


          echo " <tbody>";
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {


               echo "<tr>
                    <td>$row[Name]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Movie]&nbsp&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Year]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[ShoeSize]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[FavoriteColor]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[FavoriteFood]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[PhoneNumber]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[CharacterType]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[FavoriteDrink]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Address]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[FavoriteTvShow]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[School]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Age]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[HouseSqFoot]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[RelationShip]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Rating]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[CarModel]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[CarYear]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Boyfriend]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[NumberFriends]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[CriminalHistory]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[HappyEnding]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[FavoriteLocation]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[AppleDevice]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[WorkLocation]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Weight]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[RepublicanDemocratic]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[DressColor]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[Shampoo]&nbsp</td>
                    <td>$row[NumberKids]&nbsp</td>
                </tr>\n";



          }
           echo " </tbody>";
          echo "</table><br />\n";
     }

}
?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="scrollableContainer3">
 <div class= "scrollingArea3">
Don't find customers for your products,
find products for your customers ~ Seth Codin
</div>
</div> 
<!-- 
Searching & Result
 -->
 <div class="scrollableContainer2">
 <div class= "scrollingArea2">
<?php
    $query = $_GET['query']; 
    // gets value sent over search form

    $min_length = 3;
    // you can set minimum length of the query if you want

    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DisneyCharacters
            WHERE (`Name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`Year` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR(`Movie` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following
        echo "The result of your search is: <br>";

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
                echo "<br>"
                .$results['Name']."&nbsp"
                .$results['Year']."&nbsp"
                .$results['Movie']."&nbsp"
                .$results['ShoeSize']."&nbsp"
                .$results['FavoriteColor']."&nbsp"
                .$results['FavoriteFood']."&nbsp"
                .$results['PhoneNumber']."&nbsp"
                .$results['CharacterType']."&nbsp"
                .$results['FavoriteDrink']."&nbsp"
                .$results['Address']."&nbsp"
                .$results['FavoriteTvShow']."&nbsp"
                .$results['School']."&nbsp"
                .$results['Age']."&nbsp"
                .$results['HouseSqFoot']."&nbsp"
                .$results['RelationShip']."&nbsp"
                .$results['Rating']."&nbsp"
                .$results['CarModel']."&nbsp"
                .$results['CarYear']."&nbsp"
                .$results['Boyfriend']."&nbsp"
                .$results['NumberFriends']."&nbsp"
                .$results['CriminalHistory']."&nbsp"
                .$results['HappyEnding']."&nbsp"
                .$results['FavoriteLocation']."&nbsp"
                .$results['AppleDevice']."&nbsp"
                .$results['WorkLocation']."&nbsp"
                .$results['Weight']."&nbsp"
                .$results['RepublicanDemocratic']."&nbsp"
                .$results['DressColor']."&nbsp"
                .$results['Shampoo']."&nbsp"
                .$results['NumberKids']."";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "</table>";
            }

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results";
        }

    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>
</div>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could checkout the `contenteditable` attribute: http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/
Still I think it would be easier to actually send the data to the server if you were using normal input fields inside a form.

Comment: Hi, its not working for me, when i wrap my php table with the div and apply the content editable. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to change the content of each cell in your table you could try using the `contenteditable` attribute.

Note that I think this only will work for html5.

The following seems to work fine for me using firefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<div contenteditable="true">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Movie</td> 
      <td>Year</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Reference*: [Content Editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)

If I understand the question correctly you will also need to send the table data to the server in order to update your database. This could be done through ajax using something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var objects = [];
  $('#send-btn').click(function() {
    $("table tr").each(function() {
      var obj = {};
      // get this rows id so we know which row to update
      obj.id = $(this).data('id');
      // each td has an data attribute `data-val`
      $(this).find("td").each(function() {
        var attrib = $(this).data('val');
        obj[attrib] = $(this).text();
      });
      objects.push(obj);
    });
    // send request with data to server 
    jQuery.ajax({
      url:'update.php',
      type:'POST',
      data:'data=' + JSON.stringify(objects),
      success:function() {

      }
    });
  });
});
```

In this case you should add an attribute called `data-val` that contains some sort of identifier for the column to which the cells value belong, you will also need to know which record to update so you could set an `data-id` attribute for each row:

```
<tr data-id="1">
  <td data-val="name">Harry Potter</td>
  <td data-val="movie">Deliverance</td>
  <td data-val="year">2014-04-04</td>
</tr>
```